# How to limit the quantity of get_posts() on Instaloader

Tags: python

Im trying to find the way to do it, but the only thing i found is limit by date. Is there a way to limit the number of posts requested by get_posts()? Something like limit=10 ?

My code:

```
posts = L.get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG)
```

returning: too many queries.

Comment: Please provide a minmal, reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This line of code is the minimal, reproducible example you need. Anyway i found a solution using itertools. I'll post an answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

After a research i found a islice function from python.
With it you can achieve the requested limit.

```
from itertools import islice

# Get instance
L = instaloader.Instaloader()

# Get posts and limit them with islice
posts = set(islice(L.get_hashtag_posts(arguments), 100))
```